# Disaster recovery advice

Tags: disaster-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disaster recovery plan development best practicies or resources?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28128/disaster-recovery-plan-development-best-practicies-or-resources)

We are in the process of starting an internal evaluation about the disaster recovery procedures for our datacenter.

Can you suggest any good book/site that you consider influential in this field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/28128/disaster-recovery-plan-development-best-practicies-or-resources) on the same topic.