# Building recovery plan for HP DL380 G7 server

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, raid5, hp-smart-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disaster recovery plan development best practicies or resources?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28128/disaster-recovery-plan-development-best-practicies-or-resources)

I need your help to find out best practice to maintain my server and be ready for any kind of disk error in the feature.
I have setup the server with RAID 5 having 3 disk each 300 GB, now I need to know what step I have to take if one disk is failed?

Please let me know what steps I can take now to be prepared for any type of disaster happen to any of disks.

Comment: please read: [Disaster recovery plan development best practicies or resources?](http://serverfault.com/questions/28128/disaster-recovery-plan-development-best-practicies-or-resources)

Comment: Read through the [**Configuring Arrays on HP Smart Array Controllers Reference Guide**](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf). It will explain how to deal with disk failure on a Smart Array controller.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking here is usually best answered by HP and their product documentation.  Servers use different RAID controllers and each usually has a different method for rebuilding an array.

I would strongly urge you to contact HP for the product documentation and RAID controller information.  You don't want to rely on us when your data is gone, work with your vendor whenever possible!