# Preparing For Interview - 'IT Incedent Management & Senior Service Desk'

Tags: untagged

I have recently been accepted for an interview for a position with the state government in NSW, for the position of 'IT Incedent Management & Senior Service Desk'.

I have been to interviews before for lower positions, and some similar positions 0 but they did not have a very formal interviewing process (as I presume the state government will).

Can anyone please help me with some preperation tips that I could expect for this type of interview?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm trying to think of some passive-aggressive comment to make about the NSW government, but too many come to mind to choose a single one

Comment: Lol. Now now, if they give me a job that'd be grand :)

Comment: I think that you mis-spelled "indecent" there.  (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you what I look for in a service desk analyst or manager (general policy):

Hopefully you have some experience with ITIL or another popular management framework.
Understand what an IT service, an IT process, and what in incident refers to.
hands on experience administering at least 1 OS
Tell me how you solve a ticket for something you know nothing about "the whosit won't work with the grundersnatch".  I'm looking for you to tell me you'd find out who owns the Service that runs grundersnatch.
what makes an incompetent helpdesk staff.
tell me what you do to incompentant helpdesk staff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are actually competent and qualified for the position. If you're not nothing will really help you. If the person/s on the other side of the table are competent and qualified they will immediately know, regardless of your resume, whether you are as well.

The only advice I have, is to remember that you are also interviewing them. Make sure the shop passes the [Sysadmin Test](https://serverfault.com/questions/14832/the-joel-test-for-system-administrator-jobs). Try to get an idea of what kind of things you will be doing, how your supervisor (as he or she is presumably interviewing you) and you get on, of the WTF-level of the shop, of the stress level, etc. This takes some diplomacy, but in my opinion the interview is for both the interviewer and the interviewee.

That and **be fearless, be confident and be professional**.

Answer (score 0):

Government tends to be very focused on the resume and procedure.  Though I am unfamiliar with the hiring practices for Australian government, or even Commonwealth government, my experience working with American government has been that you will face a panel of interviewers, many of whom won't want to be there or have any idea what the position it is you're applying for is about.  The questions will likely be geared much more towards general policy and administration than anything technical, as even the technology staff will have the technical understanding of a houseplant - if that.

Dot your i's, cross your t's, and don't be afraid to suck up.